# sp_changeobjectowner

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm calling SQL's sp_changeobjectowner from C#.  I want to check afterwards if it worked. How do I check if a table's owner is who I want it to be?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the current owner name

```
select user_name(uid)
from sysobjects
where name = 'myTableName'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return value from sp_changeobjectowner. It returns 0 on success and 1 otherwise.